# Delphi XE2: How to make properties settable at design time?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl

I have a simple component

```
type
  TTimedScrollBox = class(TScrollBox)
  private
    procedure WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll); message WM_VSCROLL;
  protected
    FSkipTime: Cardinal;
    FEndTimeout: Cardinal;
    FSkipScrollTimer: TTimer;
    FEndScrollTimer: TTimer;
    FLastMessage: TWMVScroll;
    FWaiting: boolean;
    FLastMessageValid: boolean;
    FLog: TStrings;
    FSkipCount: integer;
    procedure SkipTimerEvent(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EndTimerEvent(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Log: TStrings read FLog;
  published
    property ScrollSkipTime: Cardinal read FSkipTime write FSkipTime default 100;
    property ScrollEndTimeout: Cardinal read FEndTimeout write FEndTimeout default 200;
  end;
```

I want to be able to specify values for ScrollSkipTime and ScrollEndTimeout at design time. I had the impression that all I need to do this is write the code as shown, but

1. The default values I provided don't appear in the designer and
2. When I set a breakpoint in the constructor and see what it's doing for an instance, the values of the fields behind the property are 0 even though the values I entered in the designer are stored in the DFM.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values you provide in the property declaration are only used by the streaming framework and the IDE. For instance, the property is not streamed if the value is equal to the default value. The default values are also used to allow the IDE to highlight, in bold, which values have been modified from their defaults.

What is missing in your code is that you need to set the values of the backing field in your component's constructor. We can't see that code but I'm pretty sure that is what is missing.

This issue is covered in the documentation:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Default_Property_Values
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties_(Delphi)#Storage_Specifiers

Comment: > What is missing in your code is that you need to set the values of the backing field in your component's constructor

How do I do that? _i.e._ what should be on the right-hand side of the := operator, to indicate "what was found in the DFM?"

Comment: You can't do it like that. The closest is to declare a constant and use it in both places.

Comment: @wades the DFM has not been steamed in yet when your constructor is called. So you need to initialize your fields to their default values in the constructor (`FSkipTime := 100; FEndTimeout := 200;`). And then when the DFM is steamed in later, it will overwrite default property values with their stored values. Like David said, this is covered in Embarcadero's documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it might be covered in the documentation, but I was unable to find it, and believe me it was not through lack of trying.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will have to give this another try tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: @wades in the 1st link David provided: "*Note: Declaring a default value does not set the property to that value. The component's constructor method should initialize property values when appropriate. However, since objects always initialize their fields to 0, it is not strictly necessary for the constructor to set integer properties to 0, to set string properties to null, or to set Boolean properties to False.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think my problem was not understanding that the DFM doesn't get streamed until the component is constructed. Which now that I think it through seems obvious. Thanks.

Comment: That's not it. Even if the dfm file had been streamed in the default value would not have been set because default values are implemented simply by omitting them from the dfm file.